Longest Repeating Substring With Replacement
Working on an online practice problem and ran into an issue that I can't seem to figure out. I am looking to find the longest length of a string of characters whose characters can only be replaced "k" number of times. So if we have "AABCCA" and k = 2, then the output would be 4, because at "AAAACA" i.e. changing "..BC.." to "..AA..", but if k = 1, then the output would be 3, because the solutions would either be "AAACCA" or "AABCCC" after the change.
I have the following code, and I believe it should work fine, but I am getting a runtime error - so there must be a glaringly obvious logical error on my part. It seems to be with how I'm changing the value of k, it seems to want to compare a value of "-1" to a value of "0" - but I'm not sure what might be going on. Any help is appreciated!
class Solution:
    def characterReplacement(self, s: str, k: int) -> int:
        s_split = list(s)
        long_rep_sub = 0
        l = 0
        s_counter = 0 

        while l <= len(s_split)-1:
            r = l 
            while r <= len(s_split)-1 and k > 0:
                s_counter += 1
                if s_split[r] != s_split[l]:
                    k = k - 1
                r += 1    
            
            long_rep_sub = max(long_rep_sub,s_counter)
            l = r

        return (long_rep_sub)


Your sliding window approach has not been set up properly. We can also use Counter() and take advantage of most_common():
from collections import Counter


class Solution:
    def characterReplacement(self, s: str, k: int) -> int:
        s_counter = Counter()
        l, long_rep_sub = 0, 0
        for r in range(len(s)):
            s_counter[s[r]] += 1
            max_count = s_counter.most_common(1)[0][1]
            if r - l + 1 - max_count > k:
                s_counter[s[l]] -= 1
                l += 1
            long_rep_sub = max(long_rep_sub, r - l + 1)
        return long_rep_sub


print(Solution().characterReplacement("AABCCA", k=2))
print(Solution().characterReplacement("AABCCA", k=1))


Prints
4
3
